# iOS 8 - Issue with Size Classes and Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, size-classes

I'm having a problem using size classes in iOS 8. I've created a view with two size classes, one for iPhone in Portrait (Compact x Regular) and one for iPad in landscape (Regular x Regular).

The problem I'm having is this, in any case (iPhone or iPad) when I set some text in a label, all my subviews vanish. I've noticed that only views that I use in Any x Any size class don't disappear.

Here is a little bit of the code, that makes my subviews disappear.

```
 NSDictionary *params = @{@"fields": @"*"};
[[NewsManager sharedManager] loadNewsWithId:self.newsId
                           AndParams:params
                                        success:^(News *news) {
                                            self.news = news;

                                            [self.name setText:news.name];
```

[image]

**EDIT: Added images for better understanding**

Before setting text

[image: Before setting text]

After setting text (is empty)

[image: After setting text]

**EDIT: More information**

With more tests, I found that this only happens in iOS 8. With an iPhone 4S and an iPad Simulator 7.1, it works fine.

Comment: Storyboard allows you to customize views for diff dimensions. I think you should design in Any x Any and then tweak if you want for other sizes.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done at first, but my constraints in Regular x Regular disappear after I set text to a label, and revert to Any x Any and that's not what I want

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the constraint for the label. or the label is too height for the superview , so it covers   the all subviews , so you can use the lldb po the label size ,when you set the text into the label.